# C2WTS service without ADFS?

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity

We are using a third party STS for iDM (not ADFS), when the user logins, on the relaying party side we are getting all the claims we need.

To connect to sql server, I need a windows token, and I read at MSDN blogs that I can use C2WTS service to get a windows token. STS is sending the upn claim to the application

Is it possible to get a windows token using C2WTS when we don't have ADFS but a SAML token with the right claims (including upn claim) from another STS?

Answer (score 2):

C2WTS is installed as part of WIF not as part of ADFS. It is not tied in ADFS in any way.

So if you have the "mapToWindows" attribute set in your app's web.config (as below), the claim (sent from an STS)  will be intercepted and converted to a Windows token.

```
<samlSecurityTokenRequirement mapToWindows="true" useWindowsTokenService="true" />
```

You need to turn the service on and configure the C2WTS web config. file to allow the correct user's through.

Comment: which windows accounts can I map to?
Do you know any good documentation?
For instance if the value of the upn claim is :john; can I map john to myDomain\Jimmy?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.theidentityguy.com/articles/2010/10/15/access-owa-with-adfs.html and here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-identity-foundation-wif-how-to-protect-static-content-with-the-federation-authentication-module-fam.aspx. If that doesn't answer your question, come back with a comment.